# I am getting a "Identifier identifier" error when executing a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, min

I am not sure how to fix the error that is referring to enrollment.student_id

```
SELECT std_name, course#
FROM student
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(grade) FROM enrollment GROUP BY grade)
ON enrollment.student_id = student.student_id;
```

getting the following error in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
ORA-00904: "ENROLLMENT"."STUDENT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 22 Column: 4
```

Comment: You have no `student_id` in the subquery.  The error seems pretty clear.

Comment: and also there's no alias `enrollment` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery does not return the `student_id`, so you can't reference it in the outer query. It seems like you want the minimum grade per student, so you also need to fix the `group by` clause of the subquery.

I would suggest:

```
SELECT s.std_name, e.min_grade
FROM student s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT student_id, min(grade) min_grade 
    FROM enrollment 
    GROUP BY student_id
) e ON e.student_id = s.student_id;
```

Other fixes to your query:

- you need to alias `min(grade)` in the subquery so you can refer to it in the outer query
- the subquery itself needs an alias

Note that you can get the same result with a correlated subquery - this allows students that have no enrollment at all, while your original query does not, unless you turn the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    s.std_name, 
    (
        SELECT min(e.grade) 
        FROM enrollment e 
        WHERE e.student_id = s.student_id
    ) min_grade
FROM student s
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first one did it. I am also supposed to get another column from the enrollment table. How would I go about that? The main goal is to only return std_name and course_num of the lowest grade out of all classes each student was enrolled in.